# XSLT move element in a node to another node and remove older node

Tags: xslt

I need to move element in the node to another node and remove old node I wont to convert following xml

```
 <OnBoarding >
     <child1>
        <A>0</A>
        <B>1</B>
        <C>0</C>
        <D>1</D>
     </child1>
     <child2>
        <E>1</E>
     </child2>
  </OnBoarding>
```

as below by xslt.

```
   <OnBoarding >
     <child1>
        <A>0</A>
        <B>1</B>
        <C>0</C>
        <D>1</D>
        <E>1</E>
     </child1>

  </OnBoarding>
```

I'm new to the xslt transformation. how would I do this. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a way to do that :)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <CheckList>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|child1/*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|child2/E"/>
        </CheckList>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```